# WriteLine[] not working once put into a function

Tags: function-construction, output-formatting, string-manipulation, output, writing

I wrote a function that takes two strings, an integer, and an OutputStream, it's supposed to write to. The function is:

```
UpdateFile[datum1_String, datum2_String, indexNum_Integer, fileDescr_OutputSteam]:= 
Module[{trackingNum},
If[indexNum < 10, trackingNum = "0" <> ToString[indexNum], 
 trackingNum = ToString[indexNum]]];
WriteLine[fileDescr, trackingNum<>", "<>datum1<>", "<>datum2]]
```

This doesn't appear to write anything to the text file. The weird thing is, if I just do the following "by hand" (i.e. not make a function and then call it), it *does* write to the text file.

```
fileDescr=OpenWrite[StringJoin[{"C:\\Users\\Me\\OutputFiles\\","foo.txt"}]];
indexNum=1;
If[indexNum < 10, trackingNum = "0" <> ToString[indexNum], 
 trackingNum = ToString[indexNum]]];
datum1="String";
datum2="Another String";
WriteLine[fileDescr, trackingNum<>", "<>datum1<>", "<>datum2]
```

To try to fix the problem I have:

- Made sure that the parameters I pass in when I call the function have the right head
- Used StringJoin[{trackingNum,  ", " , datum1,  ", " , datum2}], instead of the shortcut <>
- Cleared the function definition, using Clear[], and redefined it
- Quit and restarted the kernel
- Closed and reopened Mathematica

It seems like some kind of bug or glitch to me, but I'm pretty new to Mathematica in particular, so I'm not sure if this is behavior more experienced users are familiar with. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks, you guys!

Comment: Can you give an example of how you’re calling `UpdateFile`?

Comment: @b3m2a1 I am calling it like: UpdateFile["Serial","Tower",1,fileDescr]. Also, I'm not sure if it's clear, but foo.txt is created, it's just blank.

Comment: The big question is how is the file descriptor call working. And does the function return a result? If it doesn’t you know the call isn’t being structured quite right.

Comment: I  think the call to OpenWrite, that creates the output stream/file descriptor is working fine, since it returns an output stream and I was able to write to it, just not using my UpdateFile[] function.

Comment: I meant does calling `UpdateFile` return a result. My guess is you have an issue where it's not being called quite right.

Comment: It does not return anything. But, I wouldn't expect it to since WriteLine[] doesn't normally return anything.

Comment: That's good. That means the function is actually working. Which suggests you're not feeding in the right file descriptor. On the other hand, just copying and pasting your code it looks like you have a bunch of typos... You want `OutputStream` not `OutputSteam`. And you have too many parens after `ToString`   such that your `WriteLine` call is outside your `Module`. Did you mis-copy this?

Comment: I did not actually copy paste it, I typed it all out, since the input parameter names I was using really only make sense in the context of my program. I did finally fix the issue (by swapping the order of the input parameters in the definition and in the call), but I have no idea why this would have fixed the issue! I did not mention it, but my function UpdateFile[] worked for months before suddenly developing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the off chance that it would work, I swapped the order of the input parameters to:

```
UpdateFile[fileDescr_OutputSteam, datum1_String, datum2_String, indexNum_Integer]:= 
Module[{trackingNum},
If[indexNum < 10, trackingNum = "0" <> ToString[indexNum], 
trackingNum = ToString[indexNum]]];
WriteLine[fileDescr, trackingNum<>", "<>datum1<>", "<>datum2]]
```

It now works perfectly fine, but I wonder why the order would even matter.